# Target ::before with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Is it posible to target the ::before with jquery?

This is what I'm doing with no luck:

```
    $("nav").hover(function(){
        $('nav ul li a.active::before').hide();
    },function(){
        $('nav ul li a.active::before').show();
    });
```

It doesn't hide the ::before, any ideas why is not working?

Comment: Does $('nav ul li a.active').prev().hide() help you?

Answer (score 0):

`:before` and `:after` is not in DOM, so you cannot select them with jQuery/JS. Read more about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after/21709814#21709814)

Comment: Thanks, I will do a new question with another direction I'm trying to do